# How to continue code if user does not select a file in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and trying to create an email gui.  So far everything works but after adding a select file functionality to it the program will only work if the user selects a file.  I get the error

```
'GetInfo' object has no attribute 'fname'
```

Which I'm assuming means that since fname (file name) has no value added to it the program won't continue.  I tried to use a try/except thing here:

```
try:
        filename = self.fname
        attachment = open(self.fname, "rb")

        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

        msg.attach(part)


    except:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(self.frominf.get(), self.passinf.get()) #sender email, password
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(self.frominf.get(), self.toinf.get(), text)
        server.quit()

            # STOP TIMER
        elapsed_time = timer() - start # in seconds
        print ("Email took " + (str(elapsed_time)) + " seconds to send, sent to " + self.toinf.get() )
        time.sleep(0.5)
        root.destroy()
```

But this pretty much did the opposite, giving an error if I did supply a file.
So my question is: how can I let the user decide if they want to supply a file or not?

Here is my whole code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import datetime
import smtplib
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

#colors
darkred = (139, 0, 0)
grey = (90, 90, 90)

root = Tk()
root.title("Email")



class GetInfo:

    def __init__(self, master):
        #window size
        master.minsize(width=250, height=75)

        #senders email
        Label(root, text="Your email").pack(fill=X)
        self.frominf = Entry(master)
        self.frominf.pack(fill=X)

        #sending to email
        Label(root, text="Sending to").pack(fill=X)
        self.toinf = Entry(root)
        self.toinf.pack(fill=X)

        #subject line
        Label(root, text="Subject").pack(fill=X)
        self.subinf = Entry(root)
        self.subinf.pack(fill=X)

        #add file
        Label(root, text="File?").pack(fill=X)
        file_button = Button(root, text="Click to browse files", command= self.Load_file,  height = 1, bg="grey")
        file_button.pack(fill=X)

        #senders password
        Label(root, text="Your password").pack(fill=X)
        self.passinf = Entry(master, show="*")
        self.passinf.pack(fill=X)
        #body
        Label(root, text="Body of email").pack(fill=X)
        self.bodyinf = Text(root)
        self.bodyinf.pack(fill=X) 

        #submit button
        submit_button = Button(root, text="Submit(click when done)", command=self.send_email,  height = 2, bg="darkred")
        submit_button.pack(fill=X)

    def Load_file(self):
        self.fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("All Files","*.*"),
                                           ("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm"),
                                           ("Template files", "*.tplate") ))


    def send_email(self):
        # START TIMER
        start = timer()
        msg = MIMEMultipart()

        msg['From'] = self.frominf.get()
        msg['To'] = self.toinf.get()
        msg['Subject'] = self.subinf.get()

        body = self.bodyinf.get('1.0', END)
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        filename = self.fname
        attachment = open(self.fname, "rb")

        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

        msg.attach(part)



        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(self.frominf.get(), self.passinf.get()) #sender email, password
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(self.frominf.get(), self.toinf.get(), text)
        server.quit()

            # STOP TIMER
        elapsed_time = timer() - start # in seconds
        print ("Email took " + (str(elapsed_time)) + " seconds to send, sent to " + self.toinf.get() )
        time.sleep(0.5)
        root.destroy()


app = GetInfo(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `'GetInfo' object has no attribute 'fname'` mean if variable is `None` or `" "` or `""`

Comment: Your `try/except` indention are off. Treat it like an `if/else` statement for indention. Fix that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `try` and `catch`. If the `filename` exist, the `try` part code will be executed. If there's no file selected, it will go to the `catch` part and will do nothing, just continue with the code without showing any error.

```
    try:
        filename = self.fname
        attachment = open(self.fname, "rb")
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
        msg.attach(part)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, You can check whether `self.fname` exists. One way to do it:

```
if self.fname:
    attachment = open(self.fname, "rb")
```

Of course, You need to check later if You have attachment, to avoid another bug. So, further:

```
if self.fname:
    attachment = open(self.fname, "rb")

    # This part of code also should go under condition check
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

    msg.attach(part)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add the `self.fname` attribute at the start of the program and set it as:

`self.fname = ""`

Then I would change this line:

```
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
```

To an if statement like this:

```
if self.fname != "":
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

else:
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition')
```

This should prevent the error when a file is not selected.

I cannot test this right now but should be functional.